# Помогите, проблема в отображении адаптивной верстки сайта в Iphone!

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, iphone

Всем, Привет. Проблема такая: Сверстал сайт адаптивно, на всех устройствах все норм, но на Iphone отображается не так как на остальных устройствах. Position: absolute не работает.[image: Это на Iphone]

http://archiview.net/gallery.html вот ссылка
Left: 0: не помогло. Хотя на Самсунгах все норм робит.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в телефоне моего знакомого. У него айфон отображал так. На остальных айфонах все норм отображается.

Answer (score 0):

```
.gallery_bg_bottom {
position: absolute !important;
display: block;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Попробовал, не помогло.